# DataWeave and Case Sensitivity

Tags: mule

Can I turn off case sensitivity in DataWeave?

Two different requests are returning responses where the first contains a node called CDATA while the other contains a node called CData.  In DataWeave is there a way to treat these as equal or do I need to have separate code statements such as payload.Data.CDATA and payload.Data.CData?  If things were  case insensitive I could have a single statement such as payload.data.cdata.

Thanks in advance,
Terry

It appears that I need two different statements.

payload.Data.*CDATA map $.@SeqId when payload.Data? and payload.Data.CDATA? and payload.Data.CDATA.@SeqId?

payload.Data.*CData map $.@SeqId when payload.Data? and payload.Data.CData? and payload.Data.CData.@SeqId?

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can create a function like the following to select ignoring case.
Which filters an object by a given key (`mapObject` comparing keys using `lower`) and then gets the values from the resulting object (with `pluck`).

```
%function selectIgnoreCase(obj, keyName) 
  obj mapObject ((v, k) -> k match {
    x when (lower x) == keyName -> {(k): v},
    default -> {}
  }) pluck $
```

And you'd use it like this:

```
selectIgnoreCase(payload.Data, "cdata")
```

Note: With Mule 4 (and DW 2) syntax for this would be a little bit better.